# Zend Framework 2 Redirect

Tags: zend-framework2

How can I redirect to another module?

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute(null, array(
    'module'     => 'othermodule',
    'controller' => 'somecontroller',
    'action'     => 'someaction'
));
```

This doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: If you're redirecting, redirect to a route-name. If you're just wanting to dispatch another action, use the forward() helper. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is how I redirect from my Controller to another Route:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('dns-search', array(
    'companyid' => $this->params()->fromRoute('companyid')
));
```

Where dns-search is the route I want to redirect to and companyid are the url params.

In the end the URL becomes /dns/search/1 (for example)

Comment: And make sure you don't miss that "return" keyword as bad things can happen if you expected code execution to stop there without it ;-)

Answer (score 17):

One of the easy ways to redirect is:

```
return $this->redirect()->toUrl('YOUR_URL');
```

Comment: BEST BEST BEST BEST example, this worked and thats the best one.          `return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/make-world-easy?id=thank-you');`

Comment: this solution is for a different purpose: it's used for the links to other resources. in principle, it doesn't really matter, but if you need a Zend-ish approach, the accepted answer is the best.

Answer (score 6):

This is the way of redirection in ZF2:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('ModuleName',
  array('controller'=>$controllerName,
        'action' => $actionName,
        'params' =>$params));
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: `ModuleName` should be `RouteName`

Answer (score 1):

Google thinks, that this question is relevant to **zf2 redirect with anchor**, so I will add the answer here, if you don't mind. We can just use `fragment` option in third argument of `toRoute`:

```
public function doAction(){
    return $this->redirect()
         ->toRoute('chats', 
                   array('action' => 'view', 
                       'id' => $message->getChat()->getId()
                   ),
                   array('fragment' => 'm' . $message->getId())
    );
}
```

My route:

```
'chats' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/chats/[:action/][:id/]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id' => '[0-9]+',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Chats',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

So, user will be directed to smth like `/chats/view/12/#m134`