# How to send HTTP Cookies to another ZF2 Controller?

Tags: php, cookies, zend-framework2

I have two controllers. One of them is called `OAMLController` and the other is called LoginController. I would like to set HTTP Cookies in `OAMLController` and then make a call to `LoginController` and read it in this controller.

I know how to do this in PHP, but I don't know how to do this in Zend Framework 2.

**PHP (OAML.php):**

```
setcookie("_ga", "GA1.2.1622977711.1433494392", 0, "/", "http://gnsys.local");
setcookie("_gat", "1", 0, "/", "http://gnsys.local");
header("Location: http://gnsys.local/publico/login.php");
```

**PHP (login.php):**

```
$cookie = "";

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value</br>";

    if ($name == "Cookie")
        $cookie = $value;
}
```

I have tried to follow the ZF2 tutorial but is so confusing.

**More questions:**

I have redirect to the other controller using $this->redirect()->toUrl($url).

```
    $cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie("param1", "Hola", null, null, "http://gnsys.local", null, null, null, null);
    $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);

    return $this->redirect()->toUrl("http://gnsys.local/publico/login");
```

Because if I redirect with:

```
    $controllerName = "LoginController";
    $actionName = "index";
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
            "publico", 
            array(
                "controller"    =>  $controllerName,
                    "action"    =>  $actionName
            ));
```

I always access to http://gnsys.local/publico and not to where I want http://gnsys.local/publico/login.

Another question, in LoginController I can't read the cookie. If I check the cookies via Firebug I can see that I have created the cookie in ".gnsys.local" domain and not in "gnsys.local" domain.

[image]

Why has that happened? If I make the redirect using toRoute or toUrl I create the cookie on the same domain ".gnsys.local" and not in "gnsys.local".

module.config:

```
    'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
        // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
        // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
        // using the path /application/:controller/:action
         'publico' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/publico',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Publico\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

**Updated 2:**

Finally, the redirection works fine with the solution from Jangya Satapathy. But I have a new problem and this is that I can't read the cookie because the domain is not correct. With these code I create a cookie with domain ".gnsys.local" and not with the domain "gnsys.local"

```
    $cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie("param1", "Hola", null, null, "http://gnsys.local", null, null, null, null);
    $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);
    $controllerName = "login";
    $actionName = "index";
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
            "publico/default", 
            array(
                "controller"    =>  $controllerName,
                    "action"    =>  $actionName
            ));
```

So, when I try to write the value of cookie "param1", I've got the next error:

> Notice: Undefined index: param1 in /var/www/html/gnsys/module/Publico/src/Publico/Controller/LoginController.php

If we check the value of the cookies with firebug, we've got the next screen capture:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Updated 3:**

I don't understand what happened but getCookie is null.

**getcookie IS NULL**

And *print_r($this->getRequest()->getCookie());* doesn't write anything.

```
        $getcookie = $this->getRequest()->getCookie(); // returns object of Zend\Http\Header\Cookie

    if ($getcookie != null)
        echo "getcookie is NOT NULL";
    else 
        echo "getcookie IS NULL";

    print_r($this->getRequest()->getCookie());

    return new ViewModel();
```

**Updated 4:**

I have found the cookie, but I cannot retrieve its value. To find the cookie, I have to indicate the path where I'm going to read it then.

```
        $cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie("param1", "Hola", 0, "/publico/login/index", "gnsys.local");
    $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);

    $controllerName = "login";
    $actionName = "index";
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
            "publico/default", 
            array(
                "controller"    =>  $controllerName,
                    "action"    =>  $actionName
            ));
```

And, now I have this exit ...

getcookie is NOT NULL

Zend\Http\Header\Cookie Object ( [encodeValue:protected] => 1 [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( [zdt-hidden] => 0 ) )

If I try to retrieve the value of the cookie through

```
$cookie = $getcookie->param1;
```

I've got the next error ...

> Notice: Undefined index: param1 in /var/www/html/gnsys/module/Publico/src/Publico/Controller/LoginController.php on line 84

If I try to get all the values from $getcookie

```
        foreach ($getcookie as $key => $value){
        echo "Key: " . $key . " Value: " . $value . "<br />";
    }
```

And I've got ...

*Key: zdt-hidden Value: 0*

Update 5:

I don't understand anything here. I'm not creating the cookie with these code!

```
        $cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie("param1", "Hola", 0, "/", "http://gnsys.local");
    $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);

    $controllerName = "login";
    $actionName = "index";
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
            "publico/default", 
            array(
                "controller"    =>  $controllerName,
                    "action"    =>  $actionName
            ));
```

Checking the cookies using firebug we can't see the cookie.

[image]

Comment: You need to add a child route followed by the main route or else need to define a default route for your required redirect action. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you!!! But I have a new problem!!! And I don't know why ... The cookie is created with the dominion ".gnsys.local" and not with the dominon "gnsys.local" :( Please, check my update question.

Comment: print_r($this->getRequest()->getCookie()). Does it have the any other cookie apart from PHPSESSID.

Comment: Hi José. You have made a great effort here, it is good to see this sort of persistence (especially since many questions on Stack Overflow are the result of too little effort). However, the question above has so many updates it is probably no longer useful for future readers, since others are unlikely to have exactly the same sequence of problems as you did. I would therefore advise that once you get an answer below, consider asking a new question, rather than squashing five questions into the same post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your cookie set action:

```
   Public function cookiesetAction(){
      $cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie($name, $value, $expires, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly, $maxAge, $version);
      $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);
      return $this->redirect()->toRoute('cookieget'); //to your login controller
   }
```

In your cookie get action:

```
   public function cookiegetAction(){
      $getcookie = $this->getRequest()->getCookie(); // returns object of Zend\Http\Header\Cookie
      $getcookie->name1;    // value1
      $getcookie->name2;    // value2
      return new ViewModel();
   }
```

Question about [cookies in ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263446/zend-framework-2-cookie-concept).

### Answer Update

Add child route followed by the main route.

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('publicio/default',array(
                    'controller'=>$controllername,
                    'action'=>$actioname
                 ));
```

Comment: Thank you!!! But I have a problem!!! :S  I have a problem with the redirection. I want to redirect to this url: http://gnsys.local/publico/login but I redirect to http://gnsys.local/publico and I don't know why!!! :(

     $controllerName = "Login";
     $actionName = "index";
     return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
       "publico", 
       array(
        "controller" => $controllerName,
         "action" => $actionName
       ));

Comment: In this case route name (publico) should match with your modul.config file  route name.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302713/zend-framework-2-redirect

Comment: I know it and I think is correct, because If I try to access to http://gnsys.local/publico or http://gnsys.local/publico/login I don't have any problem. I have posted my config in this post